# Find the dimension of $\{\phi:V\to V\thinspace|\thinspace\phi\text{ is linear and }\phi(U)\subset U\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $K$. Let $U$ be a $k$-dimensional subspace of $V$. Consider the set $M=\{\phi:V\to V\thinspace|\thinspace\phi\text{ is linear and }\phi(U)\subset U\}$. Show that $M$ is a $K$-vector space, and find the dimension of $M$.

It was straightforward to verify that $M$ is a $K$-vector space. For the dimension, I am thinking about taking a basis $\{u_1,\ldots,u_k\}$ and extending it to a basis of $V$, namely $B=\{u_1,\ldots,u_k,v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n\}$. Then if $\phi(U)\subset U$, the matrix representation of $\phi$ with respect to the basis $B$ is of the form
$$
A^B_\phi=\begin{pmatrix}A_{11}&A_{12}\\0&A_{22}\end{pmatrix},
$$
where the representation of $\phi$ restricted to $U$ is $A_{11}$. Is this relevant, or am I going down the wrong path? Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is just fine. And it follows from that that$$\dim M=k^2+(n-k)^2+k(n-k)(=k^2+n^2-kn).$$

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: A simpler way to write it is $n^2-k(n-k)$. Which corresponds to the fact that $k(n-k)$ of the $n^2$ entries are fixed to $0$.